# DDos Mitigation Services

Tags: botattack

Any have any experience using these?  And what are the pro's and cons?  Can you expect a high level of false positives?  Are they 100% effective?

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclosure: A family member works for [Adversor](http://www.adversor.net/).**

There is no such thing as 100% DDoS protection at the minute (unless someone has more computing power than the rest of the world combined).

Some offer a range of Reverse Proxies, some use adaptive black/white listing (sometimes teaming up with other services for more accurate lists - distributed DDoS protection if you like) and the finally some use application firewalls.

Generally as long as you have protected against [Slowloris](http://ha.ckers.org/slowloris/), then your next port of call would be to look at an Application Firewall and bot-proof forms (but this requires a development style that works in tandem otherwise you'll create customer facing DoS situations not solve them).

Reverse proxies will help in the case of a DDoS (especially if they are Geo targeted so only one region would be affected). Be warned that you'll have to invest some time checking the HTTP requests/responses work properly. A lot of DDoS protection services will only point FastFlux DNS records towards their servers after a DDoS attack has been detected (to keep running costs down) so expect a bit of downtime during the switchover.

Many Webmasters with high(ish) profile sites and a low budget (generally on a single server) will just protect against Slowloris and then use code-level protection instead of application firewalls. If they need to scale, reverse proxies from a non-DDoS Protection provider (i.e. a CDN) can be most cost effective, flexible and withstand more traffic.

However if you have the budget/server-sprawl/awkward-development and want more peace of mind, you can outsource it to a specialist DDoS Protection service.